# Using QueryResults does not return anything

Tags: drools

I am trying to count the number of objects by using QueryResults. My rule is:

```
query "Test"
 m : Message()
 end

function int countFacts(String queryString) {
     QueryResults queryResults = DroolsTest.getQueryResults(queryString);
     if (queryResults != null) {
          System.out.println("Total FACTS found: " + queryResults.size());
          return queryResults.size();
     }
     return 0;
}

rule "Hello World"
    when
        m : Message( status == Message.HELLO, myMessage : message )

        eval(countFacts("Test")>0 )
    then
        System.out.println( myMessage );

end
```

And in the java side

```
public static QueryResults getQueryResults(String queryName) {
        System.out.println("inside queryResults for queryName " +queryName );
        QueryResults queryResults = kSession.getQueryResults(queryName);
        return queryResults;
    }
```

When I am trying to run the rule, execution stops and nothing happens. 
The kSession.getQueryResults(queryName) returns nothing and after some time I have to manually terminate the execution.

what is wrong here?

Comment: I think you are causing a thread lock. Any reason why you need to go outside the session (using that function) to count the number of facts? Can't you just use regular patterns to do so?

Comment: Thank you for your reply Esteban. No, there is no particular reason. My scenario is to call a query from rule and get the count and take some action based on the count ( so counting should happen in the 'when' part of the rule). I am not sure if there are other ways to do this. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here is your thread being blocked. If your requirement is to count the number of facts in your session as part of a rule, then you can do it in a much more "Drools-friendly" way using an accumulate:

```
rule "More than 2 HELLO messages"
when
    Number(longValue > 2) from accumulate (
        Message( status == Message.HELLO),
        count(1)
    )
then
    System.out.println( myMessage );
end
```

If you really want to call a query from the `when` part of a rule, you will need to [pass an unbound variable to the query](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/latest/drools-docs/html_single/#_queries_with_unbound_arguments) in order to get the result back in your rule:

```
query countMessages(long $n)
  Number($n:= longValue) from accumulate (
    Message(),
    count(1)
  )
end

rule "Hello World"
when
    m : Message( status == Message.HELLO, myMessage : message )
    countMessages($n;)
    eval($n > 0) 
then
    System.out.println( m );
end
```

Hope it helps,

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anyway, I would still like to know what caused the alleged 'thread lock'. Is it not recommended to use a helper method in case of doing something with session?

Comment: It is not recommended to invoke methods of the `ksession` while you are inside the `ksession.insert()` or `ksession.fireAllRules()`

Comment: Hello @Esteban, a quick follow up question. Is there any way to set default value for unbound variable ? For example, if the counting condition is like : [link](http://www.mediafire.com/view/rtpv8p9i0bmi6i9/Query.JPG) , in case where there is no object of type A, it will not return anything. I want to return 0. Is there any way to do that ?